# How do I catch the MobiScroll onClose Event

Tags: jquery, mobiscroll

I am using the Mobiscroll jquery plugin and i can't seem to catch their onClose event.  Can someone give me a code sample of how to catch this event.  There is no documentation for it.

THanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input[type=date]').scroller({
    onShow:function(html,inst) {
                //Personally I'd like to use events here                   
           }
});
```

That should do it

Comment: This answer lead to my answer but as of 2.0 the preset must be defined and no longer defaults to date

Comment: I use the blur event with Mobiscroll.